# Xen guest (ubuntu) does not reboot with 'no bootable device.' after change of disk size

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, ubuntu-14.04, xen, xenserver

I just increased the size of a disk in a xen (server 6.2) guest (ubuntu 14.04). After the guest shutdown it did not boot up again with the error: 'no bootable device.'

[image]

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: How did you configure the guest to boot?

Comment: What do you mean how? 
I just used a template of xen and installed the ubuntu image.

The server was already working for more than a year. With reboots.